# Is there a way to bring the current app that is running code to the foreground Xamarin Forms - Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a custom document provider for Android using this code as a base.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/storageprovider/

This allows for a new drive to be mapped onto the documents folder when browsing/saving documents.

If there is an exception due to a password timeout for example, I would like to pop back up the existing app so the users can entered their credentials again to log in.

Is this possible?  As an example of what I am looking for, if the QueryRoots failed with a particular exception, could I run something to pop back up the app interface here?

```
public override ICursor QueryRoots(string[] projection)
{
    Log.Verbose(TAG, "queryRoots");

    var result = new MatrixCursor(ResolveRootProjection(projection));

    try
    {
        if (!IsUserLoggedIn())
        {
            return result;
        }

        MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = result.NewRow();

        ... other init code here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "NoSessionException")
        {
            // LOGIC TO BRING BACK APP TO LOG IN AGAIN HERE...
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which line of the code cause the password timeout exception? How do you catch this exception? If you use the try-catch statement, could you try to reopen the existing app for user to login in again?

Comment: The code above is just example, but can you see the try catch that is there, it would be thrown in here and then caught in the catch block.. I guess the answer I’m looking for is how to either start a new instance of the app, or how do I bring the existing running app to the foreground in this catch block? Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a sample code about how to lauch the app again for your reference. You could put `Launch` method in catch statement.

In Xamarin.Forms, you could use Dependency service to start the app with package name.

Create a interface:

```
 public interface IDpendencyService
{
    Task<bool> Launch(string stringUri);
}
```

Implemention of Android:

```
 public class DependencyImplementation : Activity, IDpendencyService
{
    public Task<bool> Launch(string stringUri)
    {

    Intent intent = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(stringUri);
    if (intent != null)
    {
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    else
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

  }
}
```

Register in MainActivity:

```
 DependencyService.Register<IDpendencyService, DependencyImplementation>();
```

I use a Button event to invoke. You could try to invoke in catch.

```
 DependencyService.Get<IDpendencyService>().Launch("com.companyname.xamarindemo");
```

Screenshot: I have a button on Page21. When i click the button, it would reload the app and pop back up the existing app.

[image]